# Error when adding a new SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2013 installed on machine in addition to MS SQL Server 2012. I used to use all the Business Intelligence projects in MS VS 2013 in a very normal way. However, recently when I created a new SSIS project and then clicked on the SSIS packages in order to create a new SSIS package, I got the following error:

```
Error creating package

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B5F5B1CF-7950-436C-B3BD-E193B1F5E5A5} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)
```

[image: Error Message]

I hope the that the information I have provided are sufficient to explain my problem clearly.

Comment: That CLSID is for a SharePoint adapter.  Did you change something on your system in regards to such a thing?  Or did you do any upgrade of your OS?

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio 2013 update 5 and SQL Server SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply reinstalled the SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools), repaired my installed packages and the problem was solved.